# How to make struts property to read the value as string only

Tags: html, struts2

I want my struts property to receive the value 13235-007 as string. But when I use this code

```
<s:property value="13235-007" />
```

it returns 13228. meaning it subtract 007 from 13235.

My target value is "13235-007" as ease..

Comment: It is a string. Why to use tags at all? Simple `13235-007` will do.

Comment: actually the real code is from an arraylist of java. And I've used <s:iterator> to get the value for that. But I figured it out somehow thank you for the help sir.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<s:property value="'13235-007'"/>
```

Comment: Isn't it over-complicated a bit? ;)

Comment: Yes. I figure out with number of try.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like
     `<s:property value="%{13235-007}" />`